# Is it possible to create more than one workload identity in GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, workload-identity

Is it possible to setup 2 workload identity on the same namespace in GKE ?

If the above is possible , we are looking to assign different identifies for pods based on their service accounts .

Answer (score 5):

Yes, of course, you can attach different Google Cloud service account to different Kubernetes service account. Then specify this one that you want to use when you deploy your pods.